# Using SXSSF(APACHE POI) and adding comment does not generate proper excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am having problems generating a valid xlsx file using SXSSF poi api.
The below code generates proper excel file if I use :
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
but fails if I use:
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);

Error: Removed Records: Comments from /xl/comments1.xml part (Comments)

Please help me understand what is wrong with the code. I am looking to generate a excel file with cell comments using SXSSF api.

Actual code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();       
    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 1000; rownum++){
        Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
        for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue(address);
            setCellComment(cell,address);                
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("comments.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}

 protected static void setCellComment(Cell cell, String message) {
        Drawing drawing = cell.getSheet().createDrawingPatriarch();
        CreationHelper factory = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook()
                .getCreationHelper();
        // When the comment box is visible, have it show in a 1x3 space
        ClientAnchor anchor = factory.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(cell.getColumnIndex());
        anchor.setCol2(cell.getColumnIndex() + 1);
        anchor.setRow1(cell.getRowIndex());
        anchor.setRow2(cell.getRowIndex() + 1);
        anchor.setDx1(100);
        anchor.setDx2(100);
        anchor.setDy1(100);
        anchor.setDy2(100);

        // Create the comment and set the text+author
        Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
        RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(message);
        comment.setString(str);
        comment.setAuthor("Apache POI");
        // Assign the comment to the cell
        cell.setCellComment(comment);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and solved it by setting the row and column properties on the `Comment`.

Amending the `setCellComment()` method in your example as follows should solve the problem.

```
protected static void setCellComment(Cell cell, String message) {

    ...

    // Create the comment and set the text+author
    Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    RichTextString str = factory.createRichTextString(message);
    comment.setString(str);
    comment.setAuthor("Apache POI");

    // Set the row and column here
    comment.setRow(cell.getRowIndex());
    comment.setColumn(cell.getColumnIndex());

    // Assign the comment to the cell
    cell.setCellComment(comment);
}
```

I discovered this solution by looking at the source of the [`setCellComment()`](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/41120e00e2b33b947c6798d31edf9ae077c79a79/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.java#L921-L922) method in the `XSSFCell` class. The corresponding method in `SXSSFCell` does not set the row or column.

Comment: That's probably a bug in SXSSF, any chance you could report it in the POI bugzilla issue tracker?

Comment: I've just checked POI Bugzilla and there appears to be a bug report for this issue already: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56424

Comment: That bug looks in need of a junit unit test and a patch, both of which you have / mostly have. I'd strongly suggest you contribute both to it, so the bug can be fixed :)

Comment: That is my exact issue and this solution is perfect solution.
Saved My day. Its EOD for me though ;)